# nginx proxy doesn't wait for slow meteor app

Tags: meteor, nginx, proxy

I have a meteor app running at `meteor:3000`, but some files are served to the client very slow (up to 10s), because the server isn't powerful.

It works when accessing the meteor app directly, but using the nginx reverse proxy the files that need long to serve don't get served at all, they result in a 404.

This is my proxy configuration

```
location / {
  proxy_pass http://meteor:3000;
  proxy_http_version 1.1;
  proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
  proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
  proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
  proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
  proxy_set_header X-Forward-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
  proxy_set_header X-Forward-Proto http;
  proxy_set_header X-Nginx-Proxy true;
  proxy_redirect off;
  proxy_connect_timeout   100000000s; # these values seem to not affect nginx at all
  proxy_send_timeout      150000000s;
  proxy_read_timeout      200000000s;
}
```

[Loading the site using reverse proxy](https://i.stack.imgur.com/18rGA.png)

[Loading the site directly](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fyXbq.png)

Comment: http://nginx.org/r/proxy_connect_timeout _It should be noted that this timeout cannot usually exceed 75 seconds__

Comment: Err, show full server block config. In your images you've got error in less than 100ms. That's far less than any timeout.